# Add value when adding a line

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a code, and in it I make a supermarket cashier simulator. And when pulling a value from SQL database, it stores in a TreeView line. I can do many things with this line, anyway, I wanted it to sum the values of each line when I add it. Example: I click on add product, put the id and the quantity, and it puts this line, which it pulled from the database, there in the TreeView. And in TreeView, it has a column called "total", I wanted python to sum all columns total and join into a single number.

*Note:* Ah, I want to store if possible in a Label

```
compra = Frame(tela)
tela.add(compra, text='Realizar Compra')

def TelaCompra():

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def preco():
        banco = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="infoCaixa"
        )

        cursor = banco.cursor()

        codigo0 = codigo20.get()

        comando = "SELECT preco FROM produtos WHERE codigo = '" + codigo0 + "'"
        cursor.execute(comando)

        i2 = cursor.fetchone()


        valorT = ("%.2f" % (i2[0] * float(unidades.get())))  #Here is the part of the function to add / Aqui é a parte da função para somar

        print(sum(map(float, valorT)))


    def remove_all():
        for record in n.get_children():
            try:
                n.delete(record)
                atualizarJanela()
            except:
                tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Alerta", message="Não há linhas na tabela para deletar!")



    def selecionado():
        try:
            x = n.selection()[0]
            n.delete(x)
        except:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Alerta", message="Selecione uma linha da tabela, e, tente novamente!")


    def details():

        def funcEnviar():
            codigo0 = codigo20.get()
            unidades0 = unidades.get()

            if codigo0 == '':
                Msg = tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Alerta", message="Campo do código está vazio! Formule-o novamente.")
                return False

            if unidades0 == '':
                Msg = tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Alerta", message="Campo da quantidade está vazio! Formule-o novamente.")
                return False

            elif unidades0 == '0':
                Msg = tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Alerta",message="Campo da quantidade não pode ser 0! Formule-o novamente.")
                return False


            comando_SQL = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE codigo = '" + codigo0 + "'"
            cursor.execute(comando_SQL)
            records = cursor.fetchall()

            for i in records:
                valorTotal0 = (i[2] * float(unidades0))


            for i in records:
                n.insert("", "end", values=(i[1], i[0], i[2], unidades0, ("%.2f" % (valorTotal0))))


            for record in n.get_children():
                valores = n.item(record, "values")
                #print(valores[4])


            outro2 = Label(compra, text=f"Total de {(len(n.get_children()))} itens.", background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837', font='Poppins 24').place(x=1220, y=200, width=396, height=80)


            n.update()
            compra.update()
            preco()


        funcEnviar()


    def enviar():
        pass

    def atualizarJanela():
        outro2 = Label(compra, text=f"Total de {(len(n.get_children()))} itens.", background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837', font='Poppins 24').place(x=1220, y=200, width=396, height=80)
        compra.update()


    #Parte da compra

    #Objetos para Estilização

    caixa1compra = Label(compra, text='', background='#c1c1c3').place(x=0, y=0, width=1700, height=170)
    titulocompra = Label(compra, text='SuperMercado Alvorada', background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837', font='Poppins 44 bold').place(x=-400, y=0, width=1700, height=170)
    titulocompra = Label(compra, text='Compra', background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837', font='Poppins 12').place(x=650, y=105)

    titulo_mcompra = Label(compra, text='Painel com items da compra', background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837', font='Poppins 24').place(x=50, y=200, width=1092, height=80)



    outro22 = Label(compra, text='Total de 0 itens.', background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837',font='Poppins 24').place(x=1220, y=200, width=396, height=80)

    painel = Label(compra, text='R$ ', background='#c1c1c3', fg='#383837', font='Poppins 64')
    painel.place(x=1220, y=260, width=396, height=140)

    add2 = Button(compra, text="Remover Produto", command=selecionado, font='Poppins 14 normal', background='#252525', fg='white', borderwidth=0)
    add2.place(x=1230, y=420, width=180)

    add3 = Button(compra, text="Remover Todos", command=remove_all, font='Poppins 14 normal', background='#252525', fg='white', borderwidth=0)
    add3.place(x=1427, y=420, width=180)

    add4 = Button(compra, text="Editar Produto", command="", font='Poppins 14 normal', background='#252525', fg='white', borderwidth=0)
    add4.place(x=1230, y=490, width=180)

    add5 = Button(compra, text="Atualizar Janela", command=atualizarJanela, font='Poppins 14 normal', background='#252525', fg='white', borderwidth=0)
    add5.place(x=1427, y=490, width=180)


    n = ttk.Treeview(compra, columns=('id', 'Nome', 'valorItem', 'qtdProdutos', 'valorTotal'), show='headings')

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Treeview", font='Poppins 15', rowheight=35)
    style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font='Poppins 15')

    n.tag_configure('oddrow', background="white")
    n.tag_configure('evenrow', background="lightblue")

    n.column('id', minwidth=0, width=70, anchor=CENTER)
    n.column('Nome', minwidth=0, width=300)
    n.column('valorItem', minwidth=0, width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    n.column('qtdProdutos', minwidth=0, width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    n.column('valorTotal', minwidth=0, width=130, anchor=CENTER)

    n.heading('id', text='ID', anchor=CENTER)
    n.heading('Nome', text='Nome',)
    n.heading('valorItem', text='Valor Item', anchor=CENTER)
    n.heading('qtdProdutos', text='Quantidade', anchor=CENTER)
    n.heading('valorTotal', text='Valor Total', anchor=CENTER)

    n.place(x=50, y=273, width=1092, height=600)


    Label(compra, background='#505050').place(x=1218, y=592, width=400, height=280)

    Label(compra, background='#606060', text='Adicionar', font='poppins 17 bold', fg='white').place(x=1230, y=572, width=180)

    txt1 = Label(compra, text='Código do item:', fg='white', background='#505050', font='poppins 16')
    txt1.place(x=1273, y=640)

    codigo20 = Entry(compra, validate="key", fg='black', background='#c1c2c3', font='poppins 20 bold')
    codigo20['validatecommand'] = (codigo20.register(testVal), '%P', '%d')
    codigo20.place(x=1273, y=680, width=290)


    txt2 = Label(compra, text='Quantidade:', fg='white', background='#505050', font='poppins 16')
    txt2.place(x=1273, y=750)

    unidades = Entry(compra, validate="key", fg='black', background='#c1c2c3', font='poppins 20 bold')
    unidades['validatecommand'] = (unidades.register(testVal), '%P', '%d')
    unidades.place(x=1273, y=790, width=190)


    addBtn = Button(compra, text='╋', command=details, fg='black', background='#c1c2c3', font='poppins 20 bold', borderwidth=0)
    addBtn.place(x=1483, y=790, width=80, height=51)


    enviarBtn = Button(compra, text='Finalizar compra', command="", background='#252525', fg='white', font='poppins 20', borderwidth=0, cursor='tcross')
    enviarBtn.place(x=1270, y=45, width=300)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Olá Gustavo! The main Stack Overflow site is strictly English-only. If you feel more comfortable asking your question in Portuguese, please ask your question over at https://pt.stackoverflow.com, or [edit] your question so only English text (and your code) remains. Don't worry about making minor grammar mistakes; they can be fixed by the community.

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.